# Comparing four numbers in C

Tags: c, linux

I wrote a simple digits comparison program in C, while compiling its throwing me an error message stating that

```
**/tmp/ccX3X0AI.o: In function `main':
3e.c:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `Printf'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status**
```

The program is

```
**#include<stdio.h>

int main()

{
    int a, b, c, d ;
    Printf ( "Enter 4 numbers" ) ;
    scanf ( " Enter 1) %d, \n Enter 2) %d, \n Enter 3) %d, \n Enter 4) %d ", &a , &b, &c, &d ) ;

    if ( a >= b )
        {
            if ( c >= d )
                {
                    if ( c >= a )
                        {
                            printf ( "Enter C is Greater" ) ;
                        }
                    else 
                        {
                            printf ( "Enter A is Greater" ) ;
                        }
                }
            else 
                {
                    if ( d >= a)
                        {
                            printf ( "Enter D is greater" ) ;
                        }
                    else 
                        {
                            printf ( "Enter A is Greater" ) ;
                        }
                }
        }

    else 
        {
            if ( c >= d )
                {
                    if ( c >= b)
                        {
                            printf ( "Enter C is Greater" ) ;
                        }
                    else 
                        {
                            printf ( "Enter B is greater" ) ;
                        }
                }
            else 
                {
                    if ( d >= b )
                        {
                            printf ( "Enter D is Greater" ) ;
                        }
                    else 
                        {
                            printf ( "Enter B is Greater" ) ;
                        }
                }
        }
}
**
```

I'm not sure where exactly to point the error. At the same time I'm trying to write the same code by using conditional operators in C.

Comment: Compare `Printf` to `printf`, and make the appropriate correction!

Comment: C is case-sensitive. `Printf` is not the same as `printf`.

Comment: You have two asterisks in front of the #include <stdio.h>
Also the code would have been a lot shorter if you used std::max

Comment: You're looking for the great**est** of four numbers?

Comment: @olevegard: `std::max`? He's writing C, not C++.

Comment: Just use a sort function. The control logic is too much for just 4 numbers.

Comment: BTW: I rolled back to the previous verson containing the error. (I spent 2 minutes looking for the error to find that it had been corrected in the OQ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in the middle line here:

```
int a, b, c, d ;
Printf ( "Enter 4 numbers" ) ;
scanf ( " Enter 1) %d, \n Enter 2) %d, \n Enter 3) %d, \n Enter 4) %d ", &a , &b, &c, &d ) ;
```

it should be a small P in `Printf` => `printf`

Answer (score 2):

`printf` is supposed to be written lower-case.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: How come my answer doesn't provide answer? I wrote exact reason the error has been caused by.

Answer (score 1):

One of your lines has a typo. You wrote `Printf` instead of `printf` (the second line in main)

```
Printf ( "Enter 4 numbers" ) ;
```

Change this to `printf ( "Enter 4 numbers" ) ;` instead

Comment: And take the habit, as a beginner, to end most of your `printf` format strings with a newline (i.e. `\n`), or to call `fflush` appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

"Printf" Should be 'printf', all small letters.